# raise CompileError(msg) ImportError: Building module msanomalydetector._anomaly_kernel_cython failed

Tags: python, visual-studio, cython

While testing microsoft's anomaly detector project (https://github.com/microsoft/anomalydetector), this showed up:

> File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 414, in compile
> raise CompileError(msg)
> ImportError: Building module msanomalydetector._anomaly_kernel_cython failed: ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]

I've googled the error message but found that most people met this problem while using `pip install`, which is not my case, and their solutions do not work for me. I've also tried running the program outside the anaconda virtual environment too, but the same message still shows.

Here is the full message:

(srcnn_python38) C:\Users\jimsu\OneDrive\桌面\srcnn\anomalydetector-master>python generate_data.py -- samples sample
_anomaly_kernel_cython.c
C:\Users\jimsu.pyxbld\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\pyrex\msanomalydetector_anomaly_kernel_cython.c(612): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'numpy/arrayobject.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 412, in compile
self.spawn(args)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 518, in spawn
return super().spawn(cmd)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 910, in spawn
spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 38, in spawn
_spawn_nt(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\spawn.py", line 80, in _spawn_nt
raise DistutilsExecError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 214, in load_module
so_path = build_module(module_name, pyxfilename, pyxbuild_dir,
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186, in build_module
so_path = pyxbuild.pyx_to_dll(pyxfilename, extension_mod,
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
_build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
_build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
self._build_extensions_serial()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
self.build_extension(ext)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 414, in compile
raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "generate_data.py", line 28, in 
from srcnn.utils import *
File "C:\Users\jimsu\OneDrive\桌面\srcnn\anomalydetector-master\srcnn\utils.py", line 37, in 
from msanomalydetector.util import average_filter
File "C:\Users\jimsu\OneDrive\桌面\srcnn\anomalydetector-master\msanomalydetector_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from msanomalydetector.spectral_residual import SpectralResidual
File "C:\Users\jimsu\OneDrive\桌面\srcnn\anomalydetector-master\msanomalydetector\spectral_residual.py", line 31, in 
import msanomalydetector.boundary_utils as boundary_helper
File "C:\Users\jimsu\OneDrive\桌面\srcnn\anomalydetector-master\msanomalydetector\boundary_utils.py", line 5, in 
from msanomalydetector._anomaly_kernel_cython import median_filter
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 459, in load_module
module = load_module(fullname, self.path,
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 231, in load_module
raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 214, in load_module
so_path = build_module(module_name, pyxfilename, pyxbuild_dir,
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186, in build_module
so_path = pyxbuild.pyx_to_dll(pyxfilename, extension_mod,
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
_build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
_build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
self._build_extensions_serial()
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
self.build_extension(ext)
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_extension
objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
File "C:\Users\jimsu\anaconda3\envs\srcnn_python38\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 414, in compile
raise CompileError(msg)
ImportError: Building module msanomalydetector._anomaly_kernel_cython failed: ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2\n"]

Comment: There is probably some more useful text (the output from msvc) if you scroll up. Copy that text here (_do not post it as an image_) and we might be able to give better advice

Comment: And also tell us what command you ran. Currently your question is "I ran a mystery command and I got a mystery error" which is pretty hard to answer for anyone

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to include text error message rather than posting a screenshot of it: [Why shouldn't I post pictures of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've added the full error message and what program I was running.

Comment: The useful error message is `'numpy/arrayobject.h': No such file or directory`. If you do `import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())` what does it give you? It's there anything in that directory?

Comment: Where should I add the print(numpy.get_include()) statement? I tried adding it in front of #include "numpy/arrayobject.h" in the _anomaly_kernel_cython.c file, but nothing get printed.

Comment: Just start a python interpreter (in your anaconda environment) and run it there. This is just a test, not a modification to msanomalydetector.

Comment: There is a folder named numpy at that directory. In the folder there is arrayobject.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've somehow(?) decided to use pyximport yourself, and it doesn't know how to find the Numpy files. I honestly don't know how you've done this since it isn't in any of their files. You also seem to be using Pyrex (which was the precursor to Cython); again, I don't really know how but this isn't what you want.

Either way, this is not the way you should be importing their Cython modules.

The correct way to set the msanomalydetector package up is to run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, or by installing it using Pip. I suggest you do that in a fresh Anaconda environment with on Cython, Numpy and Pandas.